# How to create EditText fields depending on the spinner option?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-spinner

Question may seem unclear, I need to create EditTexts depending on the selected spinner option. For instance:

**Spinner:**

```
<Spinner
      android:id="@+id/spn_options"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:entries="@array/spinner_options"
      />
```

**Spinner Options:**

```
<string-array name="spinner_options">
    <item>One </item>
    <item>Two </item>
    <item>Three </item>
    <item>Four </item>
 </string-array>
```

**Activity:**

```
 spnOptions.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String chosenOption = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

      }
      @Override
      public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {}
    });
```

I have this spinner with 4 options, if the users select 3, 3 EditText will be appear under the spinner. I tried to create 4 EditTexts and set them Invisible and make them visible depending on the choice but it seems like a horrible idea in performance wise. Anyone have another idea.

Comment: Why not just use 1 `EditText` field and manipulate the data according to the selected spinner item?

Comment: @mark.jon The thing is each edittext field represents different people, so creating just one is not an option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the four `EditText` in your xml layout with `visibility="GONE"`. Then depending on Spinner selection change visibility to **VISIBLE** using `setVisibility()`

Comment: As I mentioned in my quesiton I tried this solution already but is there any other way?

Comment: It's the simplest. You can generate EditText programatically according to your chosen spinner value, then you have to remove and then add again on every onItemSelected.

Comment: That should work without appreciable lag, Maybe your performance problem is elsewhere